# Can this Google Sheet be translated in to Excel? Multiple results from lookup

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Currently trying to convert over some spreadsheets I developed in Google Sheets to Excel to fit with office IT protocol.

Two of the sheets create a drop-down list (1 from staff, 1 from companies), already struggling on this as Excel doesn't allow the data validation to just pick unique occurrences so I get each staff member or company with multiple entries repeated through the list. The 2nd issue is replicating this formula in Excel -

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(query('Datasheet - Contract Audit Report'!A2:D1000, "select B, C where A = '"&B1&"'"))," ")
```

This returns multiple results where applicable and the desired columns.

This is an example (with made-up data naturally) to illustrate what I'm trying to do - 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HS12qxJF3D_0jsmJ4pBGB1dSidpYB-9WuJ_jsy20I8g/edit#gid=352791509

Any help with the above 2 problems would be terrific! Still baffled at how Google Sheets does this so simply, yet I've spent the whole day googling solutions for excel and not one has worked!

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(query('Datasheet - Contract Audit Report'!A2:D1000, "select B, C where A = '"&B1&"'"))," ")
```

Comment: ArrayFormula & query are not supported in MS Excel

Comment: I'm fairly confident these formulas are supported with the online version of the Excel (Outlook 365). When you go "Edit Offline", it puts placeholder formulas and values so that you can still use the outputs generated when the file is online, and then syncs your changes when you save the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the spreadsheet functions are available on both applications:

- `IFERROR` is available on both apps.
- Google Sheets' `QUERY` function isn't available in Excel.
- Both apps are able to handle arrays but they handle them in different way, while Google Sheets has `ARRAYFORMULA` function, Excel requires users to use a keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, to enter an array formula, among other differences.

Consider to study the FILTER function. It's available on both apps (see below note) and it could be used instead of QUERY in some cases, like case shown in the question.

From [FILTER function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) (Excel)

> Note: September 24, 2018: The FILTER function is one of several beta features, and currently only available to a portion of Office Insiders at this time. We'll continue to optimize these features over the next several months. When they're ready, we'll release them to all Office Insiders, and Office 365 subscribers.